# How to use input variables with PromptTemplate in SQLDatabaseChain run command?

Tags: sql, openai-api, langchain, chatgpt-api, py-langchain

**The context:** 
I am using langchain and chatgpt for a text-to-sql solution. I have a defined prompt with input variables (SystemMessagePrompt and HumanMessagePrompt incorporated in the prompt template, both having input variables).
I use langchains SQLDatabaseChain for running the query. 
**The problem:** 
When I incorporate the prompt in the chain's run command I get a value error: ValueError: Missing some input keys: {'human_question', 'db_schema'}. However these variables are included in the prompt.

**Code:**

```
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain_community.utilities import SQLDatabase
from langchain_experimental.sql import SQLDatabaseChain
from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate, SystemMessagePromptTemplate, HumanMessagePromptTemplate


db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(database_uri=REDSHIFT_ENDPOINT,
                          include_tables=['dim_scenario','fact_design_level','dim_scenario_level','dim_design','dim_customer'])


chatmodel=ChatOpenAI(openai_api_key=my_openai_key,temperature=0.0,model='gpt-4-0125-preview')


system_prompt_string='''You are a PostgreSQL expert. Given an input question, create a syntactically correct 
PostgreSQL query. Never run the query. Never query for all columns from a table. You must query only the columns that are needed to answer
the question. Pay attention to use only the column names you can see in the tables below. Be careful to not query for columns
that do not exist. The customer_id is always: xxx0252d22002xxx. Always use this customer id.   Also, pay attention to which column is in which table.
Use the following format:\n

Question: question here\n
SQLQuery: SQL query to run\n

Only use the follwing tables:\n
{db_schema}
'''

system_prompt=SystemMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(system_prompt_string)

human_question='{human_question}'
human_prompt=HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(human_question)

chat_prompt=ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([system_prompt,human_prompt])

print(chat_prompt.input_variables)


db_chain = SQLDatabaseChain.from_llm(llm=chatmodel, db=db, prompt=chat_prompt,verbose=True, return_sql=False, use_query_checker=False)
```

The print command returns: ['db_schema', 'human_question'] as input variables for the prompt.
After this setup I run the chain.

```
db_chain.run(chat_prompt.format(db_schema=db_schema,human_question="How many sites does Client_x have?"))
```

And I get the following error:

> ValueError: Missing some input keys: {'human_question', 'db_schema'}

I do not understand why is this happening, as the inputs are given with the format command. What am I doing wrong, how should I input the input variables?

Thank you in advance!